# OpenGrok History Search Returns 404

Tags: tomcat, opengrok

I was wondering what might cause a 404 error when attempting to search a file's history via OpenGrok, as in clicking the H beside the filename.

Would there be a common problem that I might be overlooking?

Cheers.

Comment: Enable verbose output for clues. OPENGROK_VERBOSE=1. Also check the log files created in your OPENGROK_INSTANCE_BASE. Please post any errors or warnings...